# HTLM with Bootsrap, Images & css to PDF in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, html-to-pdf

I was using below mentioned JavaScript function for export **HTML to PDF**, even though. css and splitting the page as of break also not working. *can anybody help me to solve this issue*.

```
 function generatePDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();  //create jsPDF object
    doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById("divMainScreen"), // page element which you want to print as PDF
        15,
        15,
        {
            'width': 170  //set width
        },
        function (a) {
            doc.save("VehicleInspection.pdf"); // save file name as VehicleInspection.pdf
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divHeader">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="red" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z" />
            </svg>
            <i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i><font>DATE : 08/09/2021</font>
        </div>
        <div style="break-inside:avoid;page-break-inside:avoid;"></div>//--USING FOR BREAK PAGE
        <div id="divThree">
          //--Body Content
        </div>
```

Comment: did you try using <br/>

Comment: The question is not clear. I'm not sure what the first sentence mean. could you please clarify?